# Access Oracle DB from AWS RSD Mysql DB

Tags: mysql, oracle, amazon-rds

I have two databases. One is in Oracle and the other one is in AWS RDS MySQL. How can I access my Oracle Database from AWS RDS MySQL Database?

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: I also couldn't find any resource that discuss this issue. But I have to achieve this and for that I am looking for a workaround. Please let me know if there is any workaround to achieve this.

Comment: You need to take one step back and think what is it that you're trying to achieve, for which you thought "access my Oracle Database from AWS RDS MySQL Database" would be a solution.